# How to number the "List of Tables" in "Table of Contents"?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

This is probably a simple thing but I am stuck here.
I want to number my `\listoftables` in the `\tableofcontents` but it doesn´t work.
So far I managed to number my `\listoffigures` with the `tocbibind` usepackage and this `\renewcommand` function:

```
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}
```

but as soon as I try to convert this for the `\listoftables` it gives me twice the  List of figures instead of a numbered list of figures resp. tables

```
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lot}
\endgroup}
```

Please tell me how to fix that and just number both of them in the TOC.

Here´s my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=35mm,rmargin=25mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}

\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lot}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

bla bla bla

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You have `\listfigurename` in the redefinition of `\listoftables` again -- you mean `\listtablename` most likely;-)

Comment: Oh you´re right. Thanks alot!! Now it´s finally working :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the error was more or less a typo (see Christian's comment).